# Embedding WordPress into static site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to use wordpress in conjunction with my static site. The wordpress page will just be the gallery. I have wordpress installed in the root dir of my site to prevent an extra subfolder in the link (site.com/wp/page).

I am trying to my index page as the static on which isn't using wordpress so what I tried doing was changing the directoryindex file in the .htaccess but obviously didn't work because wordpress uses index.php to launch the wordpress environment.

Does anyone know any work around for this? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You installed Wordpress to add a Gallery to your site? That seems like a bit of an overkill.

Comment: There are plenty of good jquery plugins you can easily install that would be far simpler. You dont need to know jquery either to use most of them

Comment: its to make it easier to add images for someone that has no knowledge of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex mynewindex.php
```

this will set your main directory index to be mynewindex.php so change it to what ever index page you want .

Comment: i have tried that but when i try to log into my admin page it doesn't work.

Comment: nevermind, ignore that. It does work I just figured out the url to login to the admin page. cheers fella

Comment: I am also trying to remove the .php extensions of the static pages in the htaccess but am having no luck with the regular code you would use, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@GANIZ

Here is a way to help you achieve what you want. You can create a subdomain  *ex. gallery.example.com*  and point it to the new directory you have created in root dir.

This should make it publicly available. Then the simplest form of importing a page from the wordpress installation is with an HTML   `iframe` .  Also note that Wordpress requires a MYSQL database.